# HSO4- ion equilibrium, which side more acidic

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

I did an experiment in involving the reaction $\ce{HSO4- + H2O -> H3O+ + SO4^{2-}}$. An acid/base indicator was added to the solution. When more   $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ was added to the solution, it turned pinkish red indicating that the acidity has increased, pH lowered. more $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ should mean a shift to the left, producing more $\ce{HSO4-}$ and $\ce{H2O}$. Based on Ka values, I thought the right side of the equation should be the one to show more acidity and lower pH, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Can someone explain this?

Comment: You are correct. Adding more $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ should shift the reaction to the left, and raise the pH. I'd suspect that the $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ wasn't pure and had some $\ce{HSO4^{-}}$.

Comment: The indicator was thymol blue. I changed from a purple blue to a pink when I put the SO4 in.  Am I correct in that the color change was  opposite what should be expected?

Comment: Thymol blue is blue at pH > 9. I don't know what you have added to what, but it might have been $\ce{HSO4-}$ to a previously alkaline solution.